# How to download windows 8 on ubuntu?

Tags: windows, downloads

I want to switch back to windows, and they have a deal to download it from the website for  $40 When I click that button it brings up a windows 8 assistant that downloads, but when I click on it nothing happens. My ubuntu is completely upgraded, btw. I have wine and wine tricks as well. And I am a fairly novice ubuntu user. So please keep that in mine

Comment: Can windows 8 be installed for only $40?!! Can you give the link?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the $40 deal on Windows 8 is only for the upgrade version from Windows 7. If you'll be doing a fresh install, I still think you need to spend a couple hundred $$$.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 That's a little exaggerated. Windows 8 System Builder is the edition you'd need to purchase for a fresh install on a computer *without* a previous version of windows (you can still do a clean install with the upgrade version if you have windows already). The W8 SB costs $99, while W8Pro SB (the so called ultimate windows disk) costs $140 on Amazon right now.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is not the exact forum for this question. However, you must read the [Terms and Conditions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/terms-conditions) mentioned on the official site. It clearly states that your machine must be running  Windows 7, Windows Vista, or Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3) to download that upgrade. The only option I could see there for you is to get it shipped or buy it from a retail.

Comment: Using a Windows in VirtualBox?

Comment: You can do that if you are running Windows7/XP in VM. But I doubt that if some one is so much of a Windows user, he/she will enjoy running Windows8 on a VM.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways. I think I'll just get it shipped to us.

Comment: Why? If you have to install Windows anyways to do a upgrade, you can download it from there too. Save the dollars!

Answer (score 3):

> Each upgrade license applies to only one PC and you can install the upgrade only on PCs that have a valid base license and one of the following operating systems: Windows 7, Windows Vista, or Windows XP (SP3).

That means to install the Windows 8 Upgrade, you need Windows on your PC. So you could install any of the mentioned Windows versions and use the downloader (that doesn't work with Linux) with the Windows that you are about to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy/upgrade for $40 from Windows 8 Consumer Preview (CP)/Release Preview (RP) too; here are the links to the Win8 RP ISOs (English):

- 32-bit ISO: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=251533

  SHA1: 8BED436F0959E7120A44BF7C29FF0AA962BDEFC9
- 64-bit ISO: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=251532

  SHA1: D76AD96773615E8C504F63564AF749469CFCCD57

For other languages, go here: http://www.picohelp.com/220/download-windows-8-release-preview-iso-setup.html . Install it and run Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant from there.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: The product key should not be posted here as it may be illegal under some circumstances.

Comment: The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. :(